# How to generate mask fast where pixel is colorful rather than grayscale in SEM image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Here is a SEM image, some asssist feature lines are added on it. My purpose is to remove them.
[image: SEM image with colorful assist lines]

I found that, for native SEM pixel, RGB values should be all same or very close, for colorful lines/pixels RGB values may vary a lot.

So I write a function to extract them.

```
def filter_colorful_point(img_obj):

    def check_point_is_colorful(rgb):
        rgb = list(rgb)
        if rgb.count(rgb[0]) == len(rgb):
            return False
        return max(rgb) - min(rgb) >= 30

    colorful_mask = np.apply_along_axis(check_point_is_colorful, axis=2, arr=img_obj).astype('uint8')
    return colorful_mask
```

Here I use apply_along_axis method in numpy and compare the values in third axis, which are BGR values.

And the function works pretty good. Here is the generated mask
[image]

My question is, how could I optimize this function to make it faster? Cause I have so many SEM image to process.

Comment: So, you want to remove everything that has color, right? Convert the image to grayscale. duplicate its channels to have a 3-channel grayscale image. XOR the original image with the grayscale version. This will yield an image that has only the colored elements. Threshold that image (everything that is not black) and you should have your binary mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ptp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) (peak to peak):

```
colorful_mask = np.where(np.ptp(im, 2) >= 30, 1, 0)
```

or even simpler as pointed out in the comment below:

```
colorful_mask = (np.ptp(im, 2) >= 30).astype('uint8')
```

Comment: or just `colorful_mask = np.ptp(im, 2) >= 30` (if OP calls that "mask" they likely really just need a boolean array)

Comment: @Julien Thanks, sometimes one doesn't see the obvious :)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try and compare the speed

Comment: WOW! 30 times faster! Really Thanks!